# Create a black semi-transparent div that covers the whole screen

Tags: html, css

I want to create a semi transparent background like this below, not the white div, only the semi transparent background. tried but it does not work. This is what I tried.

[image]

```css
.container---popup {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 0px none transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
  visibility: visible;
  border: none !important;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

```html
<section class="container---popup">
</section>
```

Comment: These are commonly called modal dialogs

Comment: What you have seems correct, so maybe your html/ body isn't big enough.., you dont see anything? Try without the transition and visibility just in case..

Comment: What you have done works right. Just put some content in the page like text or image and it will appear behind the semi-transparent mask.

Comment: @praneetdixit Did that and it worked, thank you for your contribution, what happened was I was testing on a separate page without any content behind it so I could not tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

```
.popup-background {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 5000;
}
```

`z-index` of your white popup should be bigger than the `z-index` of `.popup-background`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to just have a background  behind the popup like this:

```html
<!-- Set the background here -->
<div class="popup-background">
  <section class="container---popup">
    <!-- The actual popup goes here -->
  </section>
</div>
```

Then you can just change the background of that div to the translucent black.

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can do it, *btw; you can do it in many ways*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.layer{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="layer"></div>
</section>
```